# Variation on exponential pdf expected value: integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I know that
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}t \mu {\rm e}^{-\mu t}\,{\rm d}t = {1 \over \mu^{2}}\,\qquad \mu > 0
$$

I haven't been able to figure this out with substitution:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}t^2 \mu {\rm e}^{-\mu t}\,{\rm d}t = ??,\qquad \mu > 0
$$

Was hoping someone could help?

Thanks

Mark

Comment: Try integration by parts.

Comment: As an aside, this is Euler's [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), which extends [factorials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^\infty t\mu e^{-\mu t}\,dt&\stackrel{s=\mu t}{=}&\frac1\mu\int_0^\infty se^{-s}\,ds=-\frac1\mu se^{-s}\Big|_0^\infty+\frac1\mu\int_0^\infty e^{-s}\,ds=-\frac1\mu e^{-s}\Big|_0^\infty=\frac1\mu,\\
\int_0^\infty t^2\mu e^{-\mu t}\,dt&\stackrel{s=\mu t}{=}&\frac{1}{\mu^2}\int_0^\infty s^2e^{-s}\,ds=-\frac{1}{\mu^2}s^2e^{-s}\Big|_0^\infty+\frac{2}{\mu}\cdot\frac1\mu\int_0^\infty se^{-s}\,ds=\frac{2}{\mu^2}.
\end{eqnarray}